# What are the inspirational resources for building with Duplo?

Tags: duplo

I am interested in knowing what are the inspirational resources for building with Duplo, so I can spend more quality time with them.

For example have Lego ever released Duplo building instructions similar to [Mini Builds](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/MiniBuilds)? Or what can be good web sites to check, follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LEGO does have some interesting and inspirational videos and ideas on their DUPLO website: http://duplo.lego.com/en-us/videos/

One issue with DUPLO is that it is mainly considered as LEGO for babies so all the ideas you will get on LEGO's website will be geared towards small children. However there are adult LEGO fans who also use DUPLO in their creations. Some simply incorporate DUPLO as a support-system for larger LEGO dioramas (like for building up a hill) - a method also used by LEGO's own model builders.

There are also a few adult LEGO fans who use DUPLO for building wonderful creations. One of my favorites is this LEGO DUPLO castle: http://www.flickr.com/photos/joachim_s_mueller/350719605/
Based on it, I also built a DUPLO castle myself: http://www.flickr.com/photos/akunthita/sets/72157617926473583/

In general, flickr.com is a good place to look for DUPLO creations, but again; remember that most will be geared towards small children, so you will have to comb through a lot of rainbow colored towers before you find a really good LEGO DUPLO creation.

Here is an article on how DUPLO and LEGO are compatible and can be used together: http://thebrickblogger.com/2010/12/lego-duplo/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a great site for simple Duplo building ideas: http://legoideas.si

Very inspirational!

[image: preview 1]

[image: preview 2]

Comment: LOL - Why does each and every one of them remind me of a *Crossy Road* character?
;-)

Answer (score 3):

Check [duplobuilding.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328164537/http://duplobuilding.com/), which is a nice active duplo custom building site, with an instagram and youtube channel.

Instagram: https://instagram.com/duplobuilding

Happy building!

Comment: Feb. 2017: _Server not found_

Comment: @ATV I replaced the dead link with one to the wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

Put up a small blog post here with a few ideas that don’t require complicated bricks.

https://nicksweb.co.uk/2022/04/12/duplo-easy-build-ideas/